# How to do validation of menu and submenu in jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

I have sidebar menu and sub menu something like below code:

```
     <ul id="menu">
           <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
   </ul>
```

How not getting how to do validation for menu and submneu.
can any one help to do validation

Edition:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#menuwrapper li a").on("click", function (event) {
        var districtname;
        if ($(event.target).parents('ul').length > 1) {
            districtname = $(this).text();
          //  alert(districtname);
            GetDistrictReport(districtname);
            showresults(districtname);
            //menuType = 'Sub'; //  Write your logic when sub menu is being clicked 
        }
        else {
            districtname = $(this).text();
            alert(districtname);
            GetTalukReport(districtname);
            showTalukresults(districtname);
            //menuType = 'Main'; // Write your logic when main menu is being clicked 
        }
      //  console.log(menuType + ' menu clicked. Clicked link is => ' + menuType);
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "validate menu"? How can it be invalid?

Comment: are you want to check `li` have some child or not?

Comment: If you are after a markup validation, you may use [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's inbuilt functions `.has()` or `.children()` for validating menu. These functions returns a JQuery object that contains the children, you just need to check the size and see if it has at least one child.
For e.g.,

```
$( "ul" ).has( "li" ).length ? "Yes" : "No"
```

OR

```
( $('li').children().length > 0 ) ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Comment: when I click on menu I need to do some activity and when I click on sub menu I need to do some thing else.Its working fine but every time both events are triggering

Comment: Okay I got you @user5841808 ...following snippet will serve your requirements, as
`<script type="text/javascript">`
    $( "#menu li a" ).on( "click", function(event) {
`var menuType;`
`if ($(event.target).parents('ul').length > 1) {`
`menuType = 'Sub';`
`// Write your logic when sub menu is being clicked`
`} else {`
`menuType = 'Main';`
`// Write your logic when main menu is being clicked`
`}`
`console.log( menuType + ' menu clicked. Clicked link is => ' + $( this ).text() );`
`});`
`</script>`

Comment: aaah :( ...i am unable to make formatting in comment section. You can you the aforementioned snippet for resolution.

Comment: i have changed according to your suggestion please check edition part above.But  every time if condition is satisfying

Comment: Edited code worked fine with a minor correction of appropriate selector.
Use selector element as `$("#menu li a")` instead of `$("#menuwrapper li a")`.
Do check if there are any other parent `<ul>` elements in HTML as parent of this section. If yes, then use correct identifier for selector element.

Comment: I doubt that there are other parent `<ul>` element in your HTML. Check my fiddle demo (http://jsfiddle.net/abhiii/nokbLLct) . It is working exactly as it should be.

Comment: yes as you said i have two parent some thing like above i have changed in 1st portion.In that case how to do it

Comment: Great @veenahosur, i believe answer deserve the +1.